# How to instantiate Generic class object?

Tags: c#, java, generics

I am trying to convert the following c# code into java

```
abstract class BaseProcessor<T> where T : new()
{
 public T Process(HtmlDocument html)
 {
         T data = new T();

        Type type = data.GetType();
        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty;
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(flags);
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
             string value = "test";
             type.InvokeMember(property.Name, flags, Type.DefaultBinder, data, new object[] { value });
        }
 }
}
```

So i have done upto

```
public class BaseProcessor<T> 
{
   public T Process(String m_doc)
   {
      T data = (T) new BaseProcessor<T>(); // this is not working

      Document doc = Jsoup.parse(m_doc);
      return data;
   }
}
```

When i instantiate the data object its not acquiring the properties of the Generic class at runtime
let say for example when i hit the code its not getting properties of DecodeModel class

```
IDocProcessor<DecodeModel> p = new DecodeThisProcessor();
return p.Process(doc);


public interface IDocProcessor<T>
{
    T Process(String webresponse);
}

public class DecodeThisProcessor extends BaseProcessor<DecodeModel> implements IDocProcessor<DecodeModel>
{
public void setup();
}
```

So please help me what will be the right syntax to instantiate generic object data

Comment: Look at similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1578290/891391

Comment: Generic mechanisms in Java and .NET are drastically different. You do not need a new "syntax", you need a new approach. The info about `T` is erased by the compiler completely, you cannot recover it. Essentially, everywhere you see `T`, compiler sees `java.lang.Object`

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html A good read into the behavior of generics in Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot instantiate generics**. The reason is that the type is *not available at run-time*, but actually replaced with `Object` by the compiler. So

```
T data = new T(); // Not valid in Java for a generics T!
```

would in fact be:

```
Object data = new Object(); // Obviously not the desired result
```

Read the Java Generics Tutorial wrt. to "[type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)" for details.

---

You will need to employ the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern).

```
T data = factory.make();
```

where

```
public interface Factory<T> {
     T make();
}
```

needs to be implemented and passed to the constructor. To make this work, you need a factory that knows how to instantiate the desired class!

A (rather obvious) variant is to put the factory method into your - abstract - class.

```
public abstract class BaseProcessor<T> 
{
   protected abstract T makeProcessor();

   public T Process(String m_doc)
   {
       T data = makeProcessor(); // this is now working!
```

and when extending `BaseProcessor` implement it for the actual final type.

Comment: "would in fact be:" well, no, because it would not compile

Comment: @newacct: see the Java comment behind it. And note the word "would", because it isn't (as it does not make sense to try to compile it this way).

Answer (score 1):

Tough luck; in Java the whole of Generics is strictly a compile-time artifact and the instantiation of the type parameters doesn't exist in the runtime. The usual workaround is to pass an instance of `Class` as a marker, which will allow you to reflectively create an object of that type. This is fraught with many pitfalls, but is the best you can get in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
public class BaseProcessor<T>
{
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public BaseProcessor(Class<T> clazz)
    {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public T Process(String m_doc)
    {
         T data = clazz.newInstance()
         Document doc = Jsoup.parse(m_doc);
         return data;
    }
}
```

Hint: Make sure that T has a no-arg constructor.

Comment: Its giving me error "Illegal class literal for the type parameter T"

Comment: @Eng.Fouad thanks for your help but i tried this & getting null pointer exception